# Test current node with XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

.NET's XPath functions offer the usual features like `SelectSingleNode` and `SelectNodes`. They can **only find child nodes** specified by an XPath query.

But what if I want to test the current node whether it matches a given XPath specification? How does that work?

Let's say I have an HTML document where I have found a `table` node.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="abc">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can find all `tr` elements from there. Once I've reached a `tr` element (I could also get there through navigation, not XPath), I'd like to know whether it matches certain criteria. These are best specified as an XPath string.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
XmlNode trNode = ...;
bool result = trNode.Matches("tr[@class='abc']");
```

Is this supported by .NET's (very limited) XPath functionality? Or, if that makes a difference, the **HtmlAgilityPack** package?

Comment: Why can't you just select this `tr` node and check whether it is null or not?

Comment: It is always null because it's not its own child.

Comment: What do you mean? Yo can select descendants, not only children: `//tr[@calss = 'abc']`

Comment: An element is neither its own child nor any of its other descendants. It is itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] what if I want to test the current node whether it matches a given XPath specification?

You can check that with the `self::` axis.
So if your current node is `tr` and you want to check if the current `tr` element is one with a `class` attribute with the value `abc`, use the following XPath expression:

```
self::tr[@class='abc']
```

I guess that this is what you want, isn't it?